# How to show the tab bar item's icon correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have created an application using storyboard and has a tab bar controller with 3 tabs. Each tab has a tab icon and a tab title, and I have two styles images (checked and unchecked) for the tab icons. Both are 54*54.

[image: checked is blue]
[image: unchecked is gray]

When I select the tab bar item using storyboard, in its attributes inspector, 
If I set the Bar item's Image to be the checked one , it will show some strange thing like this:

[image: strange]

Of course that's not I want. I guess maybe the problem is that my checked icon is blue.

I am wondering how can I get the right icon for the tab. Both in right size and appearance.

Also, could someone tell me what's the difference about "Tab Bar Item" and "Bar Item"?

[image]

Comment: Resize the image in Preview and re-add it to the project? It should be 30x30 for @1x if I remember correctly.

Comment: The size issue is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the problem with 'strange thing' with the image, you can do this in code: (Sorry, I don't know the proper word for that either)

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Then assign this image to the UITabItem's image:

```
UITabBarItem * tabItem = [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
tabItem.image = image;
```

I don't exactly know how you can do this in storyboard.

You could also resize your image to the correct size, either outside (using preview) or inside, with code (Search for a method to resize an UIImage).

Comment: I find a way to solve this: just use the unchecked one and make it "2x" in Images.xcassets. I guess maybe the problem is the checked one is blue.

Answer (score 2):

- Size Issue: I recommend you to use `Sketch` as you App Icon Tool which is capable of importing your icon, custom one or downloaded one, to three size (@1x,@2x and @3x) conveniently. And I do not recommend you set your icon's size in the code.
- Highlight Issue: You showed you have different-light types for icon, you can set blue one as the highlight-icon for `Selected Image` in the panel `Tab Bar Item`.
- Item Bar Issue: I think the `Bar Item` is part of `Tab Bar Item`. If you just used the `Default` icon, like `More`, `favorited`, `feather`, then you do not need to set the `Tab Bar Item`. And you shall choose your own `icon` in the `Tab Bar Item` after you selected the `System Item` as `Custom`.

Answer (score 0):

I just meet the same question!And then I figure out it!

**There is nothing wrong with your code or setting**

It's about your **IMAGEs**

You can just look at the apps on your phone.(almost)Any tab bar item icons are in gray.

So the Icon will just display their **UN Hollow** parts in gray!!

[Additionally,according to official API,they wrote like this:

By default, unselected and selected images are automatically created from the **alpha values in the source images**. To prevent system coloring, provide images with ***UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal***.

]

Consequently the solution is : USE Sketch to make your instance's icon heart-part to be hollow